# Mysql Query performance issue

Tags: mysql

We run our systems on a dedicated server with the following spec

- Dual Xeon 2.8Ghz
- 8GB RAM
- 2 x 250GB Storage
- 1TB Monthly Data Transfer

All my code is in php and databases are mysql

Currently we have around 500k records in our database; this is likely to increase by at least 500k every year

I am facing an issue of a very high load time of one of our main pages. 
I  have noticed that on their local server the load time is 2 secs and on our server it is 18 seconds.Using same query and an exact copy of server database on the local server.

**What steps would you take to find out why there is such a large difference in load times?**

**Each call that comes through our system is loaded into database. Currently there are 370k records**
Each call is associated with a campaign, tariff and pricing model. 
Our queries calculate:

a)  Total number of calls per campaign, 
b)  Total call charges per campaign

The problem is that much of the data, (call charges) can changed in the past by updating tariffs, pricing, campaign start dates, end dates etc.  This has led to some instability as the table includes the call charges
The alternative is to calculate call charges on the fly. So to calculate it in the code every  time there is a query. However there are 400k records, and this is likely to increase by a million every year

What is the best way to do this?
Please see the query strings below:

a) Platform Campaign Lead Data Query

```
SELECT c.tariff, c.campaign_name, c.ad_status, c.ad_control, cd.company, cd.customer_name, pm.pricing_model_name, c.start_date, c.end_date,
(
SELECT p.payment_date
FROM payments p
WHERE p.campaign_id = c.campaign_id
ORDER BY p.payment_date DESC
LIMIT 1) AS LastPaidOn,
(
SELECT p.payment_amount
FROM payments p
WHERE p.payment_status = 'Complete' AND p.campaign_id = c.campaign_id
ORDER BY p.payment_date DESC
LIMIT 1) AS LastPaidAmount,
(CASE WHEN NOW() BETWEEN c.start_date AND c.end_date THEN 'Live' ELSE 'Dead' END) AS STATUS,
(CASE WHEN c.group_name = c.campaign_id THEN '' ELSE c.group_name END)
 AS group_name_processed,
(
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(call_leads_purchased),0)
FROM payments
WHERE campaign_id = c.campaign_id AND payment_status = 'Complete') AS CallLeadsPurchased,
(
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(cd.call_leads_used),0)
FROM call_data cd
WHERE cd.campaign_id = c.campaign_id) AS CallLeadsUsed
FROM campaign_data c
JOIN customer_details cd ON cd.customer_id = c.customer_id
JOIN pricing_model pm ON pm.pricing_model_id = c.pricing_model_id
HAVING STATUS = 'Live'
ORDER BY c.campaign_name
```

b) Dashboard Queries

/*For Calls Summary*/

```
SELECT
(
SELECT SUM(call_leads_used)
FROM call_data cd
WHERE 1 = 1 AND cd.call_date >= '2010-03-06' AND campaign_id IN(6)) AS SummaryCallLeadsUsed,
(
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM call_data cd
WHERE 1 = 1 AND cd.call_date >= '2010-03-06' AND campaign_id IN(6)) AS SummaryReceivedCalls,
(
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM call_data cd
WHERE 1 = 1 AND cd.call_date >= '2010-03-06' AND campaign_id IN(6) AND cd.call_status = 'Unanswered') AS SummaryUnanswered,
(
SELECT SUM(call_leads_used)
FROM call_data cd
WHERE campaign_id IN(6)) AS TotalCallLeadsUsed,
(
SELECT SUM(call_leads_purchased)
FROM payments
WHERE campaign_id IN(6) AND payment_status = 'Complete') AS TotalLeadsPurchased
```

/*For Pie Chart*/

```
SELECT
'Free Calls' AS TYPE, COUNT(*) AS calls
FROM call_data cd,
campaign_data cad
WHERE cd.campaign_id = cad.campaign_id AND cd.call_date >= '2010-03-06' AND cd.is_processed = 1 AND cd.applied_charges = 0 AND cad.customer_id = 6
GROUP BY cad.customer_id UNION
SELECT
'Charged Calls' AS TYPE, COUNT(*) AS calls
FROM call_data cd,
campaign_data cad
WHERE cd.campaign_id = cad.campaign_id AND cd.call_date >= '2010-03-06' AND cd.is_processed = 1 AND cd.applied_charges > 0 AND cad.customer_id = 6
GROUP BY cad.customer_id

/*For Calls per day chart*/
SELECT COUNT(*) AS calls, DATE_FORMAT(call_date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS call_day
FROM call_data cd,
campaign_data cad
WHERE cd.campaign_id = cad.campaign_id AND cd.call_date >= '2010-03-06' AND cd.is_processed = 1 AND cad.customer_id = 6
GROUP BY call_day
ORDER BY call_day

/*For total pages */
SELECT COUNT(*) AS expr
FROM call_data cd,
campaign_data cad
WHERE cd.campaign_id = cad.campaign_id AND cd.is_processed = 1 AND cd.call_date >= '2010-03-06' AND cad.customer_id = 6

/*Calls data*/
SELECT
cad.campaign_name,
cd.call_date,
cd.caller_id,
cd.call_duration,
cd.call_status,
cd.call_duplication,
cd.applied_charges
FROM call_data cd,
campaign_data cad
WHERE cd.campaign_id = cad.campaign_id AND cd.is_processed = 1 AND cd.call_date >= '2010-03-06' AND cad.customer_id = 6
ORDER BY cd.call_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

Comment: I'm assuming you haven't configured your mysql instance and that you're running with default settings, which means mysql hasn't used any of its advanced features for saving the working set of data in memory and you're reading everything directly from HDD. Run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer_pool%'`, post the output of that. Show us what indexes you use on the mentioned tables and add `EXPLAIN` in front of every `SELECT` query you have, run it and check what it says.

Comment: +N.B's suggest, are they InnoDB tables? in that case, you need to take a look innodb_buffer_pool_size... etc.